# login using curl

Tags: php, curl

After logging in using curl the css and javascript files are linking to localhost how to overcome this.....

I have logged into external website using curl
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://externalwebsite.com");
after getting redirected to the external website the links in the external website are showing the localhost path
for example the javascript files are linking to 

the above path is linked to  src="http://localhost/curlbasic/js/dojotoolkit/dojo/dojo.js?12.01_144204"

Comment: I think you'll need to describe this problem in more than one sentence.

Comment: Edit your question and add the HTML (at least the `<link>` and `<script>` tags)

Answer (score 1):

After reading question details are not visible how to get those...

In answer to your edit. I think the website you're leeching uses relative URL. So, to get good URLs you need to replace all their relative path to absolute paths.

So, for example, you'll have to replace

> src="js/dojotoolkit/dojo/dojo.js?12.01_144204"

by

> src="https://externalwebsite.com/js/dojotoolkit/dojo/dojo.js?12.01_144204"

Comment: @user No. You can not *expect* help. Nobody here is obliged to help you figure out vaguely worded problems or do your work for you. The best way to *receive voluntary help* is to provide a good description of your problem with as much relevant detail as you can possibly provide. And be polite in the process.